# Can I submit 2 apps with nearly the same content but different in language?

Tags: android, ios, submission

I want to submit one for App store/Play Store of Chinese language in Hong Kong, and one for App store/Play Store in English as Hong Kong has 2 official languages. Can I do this?

If I could do that, can I set one only available on Hong Kong's Chinese App store/Play Store and the other one only available on Hong Kong's English App store/Play Store?
I want to make users using Chinese App store/Play Store will not see the English version. Vice versa.

I know that may be violate the Review Guidelines of App store/Play Store. But I still want to know the 
feasibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While you submit an app, you can select the location where you want your app to be available in the same way submit both your apps & select appropriate available regions for both the apps. This will solve your purpose.